# AJAX Calendar Extender / Textbox values always null after postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

Im sure this is a very simple and easy to answer question but I've been looking at this too long and being new to ASP I cant seem to find a solution that works.

I have an ASP calendar extender, I click it and the calendar displays as expected, the selected date appears in the textbox, but when the page then posts back I cant get the selected date value from either the textbox.text or the calendarextender.selecteddate properties, I tested this by trying to assign these values to a string variable in the page_load event.

Am I missing something here?

Here is my code so far:

I have the script manager declared at the start of my form

```
   <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
```

Then my textbox / datepicker within  table lower down

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="DateChooser"  
                     runat="server" 
                     ReadOnly="true"
                     style="text-align: center" Width="85px" 
                     OnTextChanged="DateChooser_TextChanged"
                     AutoPostBack="true" />  

         <div style='position:relative; z-index:1'>

            <cc1:CalendarExtender CssClass="cal_Theme1" 
                                  ID="DateChooser_CalendarExtender" 
                                  runat="server" 
                                  Enabled="True" 
                                  TargetControlID="DateChooser" 
                                  PopupPosition="Right" 
                                  Format="dd MMM yyyy" 
                                  />
      </div>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have set textbox ReadOnly to true it lose changes performed by client-side code on postback. Follow this link for more detailed explanation: [TextBox.ReadOnly Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.readonly.aspx) Consider to set readonly attribute on textbox by client code.

Comment: Thanks, I had never thought that the read only property would let the textbox loose its changes. I'll look into setting that another way.